# How to organize or format widgets in Flutter code in Visual Studio Code (Windows)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I am working with Flutter code and I am using Visual Studio Code on Windows, I am wondering about the best way to organize or format my widgets.

I tried to look for an extension in Visual Studio Code but with no result, I didn't find it.

Comment: Have you tried running ```flutter format .``` in the terminal to fix any formatting issues?

Comment: @Karma Thank you for you help, could you please explain more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide you with a helpful guide on how to organize and format widgets in Flutter code using Visual Studio Code on Windows.

It seems like the code before the command is similar to this:

[image: Your code before the command]

then,

[image: will be more clear and organized]